# Can I subscribe to all topics on a crossbar.io broker with a single subscription?

Tags: crossbar, wamp-protocol

I'm trying to monitor all topics published on a crossbar.io broker.  My attempt so far is to subscribe to topic="" with matching policy of 'prefix' but that doesn't seem to work, whereas topic="a" with matching policy of 'prefix' does see all events for topics starting with 'a'.

Is there a way to monitor the whole lot?

Comment: I'd recommend namespacing topics anyway, like `com.example.topic1`; then subscribing to the `com.example` prefix would do…

Comment: I agree that namespacing is  good idea, but this is a privately used server on a LAN and could potentially have any topic published.  We do have a home-grown broker application and that does allow the 'prefixed with ""' notation to match all - I was hoping crossbar had an equivalent.

Comment: This does indeed not seem to be possible. Could you file an issue with Crossbar.io (https://github.com/crossbario/crossbar/issues)? I don't know if there is a reason for why this shouldn't work, but Crossbar.io should not register the subscription if nothing will ever be published.

Comment: Ok, I've reported it as an issue - thanks!

Comment: I may have answered this myself, having read the spec yet again.  The argument to the subscribe is a uri and the WAMP spec says that a uri cannot be an empty string and thus it is invalid.  On the other hand, it would be nice if it worked...